# Unknown error in login popup

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

I'm an administrator of a facebook app called Qubit.
We use the facebook login button (the fb:login-button ), and since 22/11 aprox. we are having an strange behavior.
When a user clicks the button, the facebook popups opens, but it gives a generic error saying "try again later", without a code or something to know what is wrong.
What I need is to know what's wrong, or if exists some kind of debugging tool to see the error code, or what's wrong in my application so I can fix it.
The url of the popup is:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/plugin.perms?display=popup&app_id=151168321675896&perms=email&secure=true&social_plugin=login_button&return_params=%7B%22scope%22%3A%22email%22%2C%22size%22%3A%22large%22%2C%22login_text%22%3A%22Conectate%20con%20Facebook!%22%2C%22app_id%22%3A%22151168321675896%22%2C%22locale%22%3A%22es_LA%22%2C%22sdk%22%3A%22joey%22%2C%22channel%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D17%23cb%3Df32cdf8178%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsecure.qubit.tv%252Ff7f7b014%26domain%3Dsecure.qubit.tv%26relation%3Dparent.parent%22%2C%22ret%22%3A%22perms%22%7D&login_params=%7B%7D

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `show_error=1` to the URL parameters shows,

```
API Error Code: 1
API Error Description: An unknown error occurred
Error Message: kError 1349040: Invalid Application ID: The provided Application
                               ID is invalid.
```

(Assuming that the application ID in the URL you’ve given is the actual one.)